# Undefined reference to constructor in Clion

Tags: c++, oop, linker-errors, clion

I'm working on a small OOP project and when I try to build my project, it says "undefined reference to " function_name or constructor.
I clearly implemented the code and the file names are in CMake.txt as executables...

here's the GitHub repo for all the files

https://github.com/PierreNabil/BoardGame.git

Please Help
thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post links to code. [edit] and add the code you your question. If possible, create a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: It's a simple program really!
the only problem is that the linker doesn't find the definitions of the functions/constructors